# Unable to access Lead Schema

Tags: leads, schema

I am unable to get the schema of the Lead object using:

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Lead')
```

this is returning null.

I did not have any problem while getting the schema of Account or Contact.

In my dev environment I **DO** got success to get the Lead schema, but no luck on the production environment.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some more context? Where are you trying to call this code? What API Version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try an see if the "lead" is coming in the debug or not to check?

```
Schema.SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Lead');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> objMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(String str : objMap.keySet()) {
    System.debug(str + ' = '+ objMap.get(str));
}
```

Post the result from the above code.

Comment: I checked and the user has full administrative rights ("System Administrator"). And I can see that he has the permission for Lead as same as Contact or Account.

Comment: Permissions issues should not block you from seeing the schema.

Comment: Also note that `Schema.SObjectType.Lead` yields *exactly the same describe* as `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Lead')`.

Comment: Edited the answer. please try the code to check if the Describe is returning the Lead.